Getting error while hosting MERN Project on AWS: .env file error
Upload the file on the aws ec2 instance using GitHub so after that I use pm2 to start the server file, but it shows an error that the server is running on an Undefined port and a mongodb error,
but when I run the same file on my system it works fine
It is like that the path  dotenv.config({path : "backend/config/config.env"}) is not recogninzing by instance?
Is there any different method for path to define, or any other method to host my MERN APP on aws hosting service

Are you sure that you got all the files on EC2 instance? Noone can help you without more information about what you did, what's the project structure etc.
